# How can I position InfoWindows based on screen position, instead of map position?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

My custom infoWindows are larger than the default. This means I have to lower the point in which the map centers upon clicking a marker, so that the infoWindow will be shown fully. The problem is, since I move the map position down by a specific amount of latitude, when the map is zoomed in close, the offset is too great. Inversely, when the I zoom far out, it doesn't move down enough. How can I position the infoWindow relative to the screen height?

Default look of screen. X is anchor of infoWindow

```
|-----|
|-----|
|--X--|
|-----|
|-----|
```

What I want: (No matter the zoom level)

```
|-----|
|-----|
|-----|
|--X--|
|-----|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lower the point at which the map centers on a marker can be done.  Sorry but you loose the default info window implementation.  *Don't worry your custom info window will easily port to this method*.  This is a very good thing to handle `onMarkerClick` because now your info window can handle buttons link to external content, anything the info windows do on the google maps application like a nav button can be done at onMarkerClick() with a popup window or dialog fragment.

Follow these steps.

1. tell the map you are handling the onMarkerClick. `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);`
2. override onMarkerClick(Marker marker) to
3. Display a popup window
   http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html
   or dialog fragment.
4. Move the map so your marker is at the bottom of the screen. 
   Calculating the new lat lon involves taking into account the zoom and the direction of north.  [This library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)
   will help. `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(markers newlat newlon));`
5. `return false;` from the onMarkerClick event to tell android your
   handling the marker.

Note return true from onMarkerClick() for markers you want to use the default map info window.

Comment: This is closer to what I did than the other solution. Though both were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

1.) Don't create/add the default InfoWindow to your marker

2.) Instead add an event handler ( OnMarkerClickListener ) to your marker

3.) In that clickhander, "compute" where you want your infowindow to appear

For example, get the

```
Projection projection = map.getProjection(); // get map projection
VisibleRegion vr = projection.getVisibleRegion(); //
```

With vr, you can get the lower-left corner coordinates of your screen. Add a few points to that corner, and you can call

```
LatLng infoLL = projection.fromScreenLocation(Point infoPoint);
```

to get the coordinates of where you want your InfoWindow to appear

4.) Create a "dummy marker" on the fly (e.g. one pixel image) such that it is invisible using the location you computed above (infoLL)

5.) Add your InfoWindow data into it

6.) Immediately call showInfoWindow() into it

7.) As an option, add an OnInfoWindowClickListener into it, to delete the dummy marker if clicked, or a delayed delete

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand this solution. It seems like the infoWindow would not appear over the selected marker; possibly over top of it, or far above it, despite it being centered correctly.

Comment: @Phiat This would work but I'm curious if you tried to move the map, call showinfowindow with an infowindow anchored above the marker, and finally return false from onMarkerClick() without creating a temp marker would work for the user.  showinfowindow doesn't say anything about moving the map in the documentation and it would definately be easier than my solution below and your solution of the temporary marker.

Comment: Yea. I ended up getting the result I wanted by adjusting the center point of the map by different amounts for each zoom level. A little sloppy, but it works for what I wanted. Thank both of you for your help and guidance, you both provided helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

### InfoWindows static position on your map

I know its to old and somewhat completed  problem but after working 4-5 hour R&D finally i am on this stage to do something different stuff.

In this scenario I Use **fragment** instead of **infowindow**  for more reliability.

First of all click on below link :)

[Sticky Infowindows](https://gist.github.com/vishalpatel1327/ccc3073e1b483b22510ec80bbb58bc91)

in this Guist i added 3 files

**1) customeMapview..java** [link](https://gist.github.com/vishalpatel1327/ccc3073e1b483b22510ec80bbb58bc91#file-customemapview-java)

this is custom mapview  Use it  at your xml file.

**2) maps_fragment.xml**  [link](https://gist.github.com/vishalpatel1327/ccc3073e1b483b22510ec80bbb58bc91#file-maps_fragment-xml)

I just put my Infowindow below at the map
if you want upper side ,left side , you can set your framlayout with your perspective.make sure         ***android:clickable="true"***  at your framlayout for cancle bottom map click.

3)**MapsFragment.java** [link](https://gist.github.com/vishalpatel1327/ccc3073e1b483b22510ec80bbb58bc91#file-mapsfragment-java)

first of all **onMarkerClick**  set your fragment transition.

lets move on your customMapview's **mapview.setCustomEventListener**  inside

> if (intersects) {}

your main basic code to hide your customInfo window.

and you can set your **interface** at here bottom

```
 //custome listner to fetch data from Custom map view because map does't allow  anu touch/click listner 
public interface OnCustomEventListener {
    void onEvent(MotionEvent ev);}
```

Enjoy the custom static infowindow for  map
any question or suggetion please tell me at below comment

Comment: Can you please share any working demo or example how it would be looking with this approach ? Can you share a complete project ? I would like to implement *info window* to right side of marker.

Comment: What is *TestFragment* inside *MapFragment* here i am not be able to get into working this approach can you suggest further ?